# Replace single quotes from list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am querying bigquery to get its schema which is returning the below list

`['word STRING', 'word_count INTEGER', 'corpus STRING', 'corpus_date INTEGER']`

From this output list, I am trying to replace the single quote with empty and `INTEGER` with `BIGINT` using below code.

```
# Output from the query    
result = ['word STRING', 'word_count INTEGER', 'corpus STRING', 'corpus_date INTEGER']
result_new = [string.replace("INTEGER", "BIGINT").replace("'", "") for string in result]
result_new = 'create table {} {} stored as orc;'.format(table_id, result_new)
print(result_new)
```

Its returning result as:

`create table shakespeare ['word STRING', 'word_count BIGINT', 'corpus STRING', 'corpus_date BIGINT'] stored as orc;`

where my desired output is:

`create table Shakespeare (word STRING, word_count BIGINT, corpus STRING, corpus_date BIGINT) stored as orc;`

Since I am completely new in Python, I googled and tried many things but is replacing `INTEGER` into `BIGINT` but not working for replacing other things.

Is there any convenient way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are using the list representation, which includes square brackets and quotes, the quotes are not in the strings themselves but in the representation of the list, that python automatically generates when you include it in another string with `.format`.

A better approach is to build the string the way you want directly:

```
result = ['word STRING', 'word_count INTEGER', 'corpus STRING', 'corpus_date INTEGER']
# turn integer into bigint
result = [x.replace('INTEGER', 'BIGINT') for x in result]
# join the strings in a single string using comma as separator:
result_new = ', '.join(result) 
sql = 'create table {} ({}) stored as orc;'.format(table_id, result_new)
```